# Where does Microsoft IIS stores its settings?

Tags: iis

Where I can I find the config file For Microsoft Windows IIS 7.5, that has the physical path in it for example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IIS 7 and above introduced an XML based configuration system found in the following directory:

%WinDir%\System32\Inetsrv\Config

By physical path I'm assuming you mean a website's, which is found in:

%WinDir%\System32\Inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config

For further information visit:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference

Comment: Thanks! Was it possible to edit this before IIS7?

Comment: No. This was introduced beginning with IIS 7.

Comment: in IIS 6, Metabase.XML (\system32\inetsrv) stored these settings (different format). IIS 5 and earlier used a binary metabase format.

Comment: if you're on 64 bit, there is also this location: `%WinDir%\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config`